# Rails In Place Editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm using rails 3 and am trying to use the in_place_editing plugin:

http://github.com/wanglian/in_place_editing

```
 # Controller
  class BlogController < ApplicationController
    in_place_edit_for :post, :title
  end

  # View
  <%= in_place_editor_field :post, 'title' %>
```

However I'm getting the error:  id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

I'm calling the plugin in my photo_album controller, which has a title attribute...

```
class PhotoAlbumsController < ApplicationController

  in_place_edit_for :photo_album, :title
```

The in the Index View, I'm doing the following:

```
<% @photoalbums.each do |photoalbum| %>
     <%= in_place_editor_field :photoalbum, 'title' %>
<% end %>
```

Does anyone understand this or have experience with this plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because, its trying to update the title of a nil object. You should use this instead

```
<% @photoalbums.each do |photoalbum| %>
     <%= in_place_editor_field photoalbum, 'title' %>
<% end %>
```

if you see the code of the plugin the definition of the method is

```
def in_place_editor_field(object, method, tag_options = {}, in_place_editor_options = {})
```

Comment: Still: Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Comment: <% @photoalbums.each do |photoalbum| %>
   <%= photoalbum.inspect%>
:   #<PhotoAlbum id: 3, title: "Bark", description: nil, user_id: 1,

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to use `in_place_editor_field` in a loop, do something like this:

```
Class Item < AR::Base  
  #attributes like name, price  
end  

<% for some_item in @items %>  
<% @item = some_item %>  
<%= in_place_editor_field :item, :price %>  
<% end %>
```